# Save data in profile

Tags: database, facebook, user-profile

I'm trying to handle a Facebook login on my homepage. Now I have the Problem that I need to save a choosable option from my site for every user who logs on with Facebook.

Is it possible to save this option in the user profile or must I save it in my own database?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to save this option in the User-Profile or must i save it in my own Database?

No, Facebook does not offer anything to store app-relevant user data on their servers.

You’ll have to use your own database.